# Page URLs in 2013 - ribbon option disabled

Tags: 2013, ribbon

I'm wanting to check out the "Page URLs" option in SharePoint 2013, but in the ribbon that option is disabled. All the others are available to me (as the site collection admin and in the authors/admins, etc. group), but this one is not.

Any ideas why this one specifically is disabled? Is there a site/site collection feature somewhere that needs enabling perhaps?

Cheers

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about Friendly URLs?Make sure the site is using Managed navigation for this functionality. There are some blogposts around describing each en every part of this type of navigation and how to configure friendly urls. This one I like http://sadomovalex.blogspot.se/2013/04/managed-metadata-navigation-and.html

Comment: I managed to work this out, but had forgotten that I'd asked this question. Your info regarding Managed Navigation was indeed the answer.